# Neo4J's create, pull, and create_unique

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

We're using Neo4J and Python (py2neo).  Can I get confirmation that `graph.create()`, `graph.pull()`, and `graph.create_unique()` all "commit" their work, in SQL speak? They sure seem to, but this is not the right time to assume.

I've read [this page](http://py2neo.org/2.0/intro.html) but I am not seeing words like "permanently" with respect to the writes.  In a SQL database, an uncommitted transaction looks permanent while one is in the transaction...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see exactly what is going on by using `py2neo`'s `watch`:

```
>>> from py2neo import watch, Graph, Node
>>> watch("httpstream")
>>> graph = Graph()
>>> nicole = Node("Person", name="Nicole")
>>> graph.create(nicole)
> POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher [80]
```

So you can see that `graph.create` is using the [legacy Cypher endpoint](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-cypher.html). If you want to use the transactional endpoint, you'd be better off using transactions:

```
>>> tx = graph.cypher.begin()
>>> tx.append("CREATE (n:Person) SET n = {props}", props={"name":"Nicole"})
>>> tx.commit()
> POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit [137]
```

Which is clearly using the [transactional endpoint](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html).

Comment: But, to be clear, the legacy Cypher endpoint is also transactional. It just does not allow you to keep the same transaction open across multiple Cypher requests. Instead, it commits at the end of each request. Therefore, there is no need to fear :-).

Comment: True, also you can't execute multiple statements at once, which imo is a bigger disadvantage than holding a tx between requests.